# Error when casting and referencing Page from dynamically added User Control

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I have an ASP.NET 4 web site (NOT web application).

One one ASPX page (Router.aspx) I dynamically add a ASCX user control to a placeholder at runtime based on the requested URL. In the user controls I need to retrieve properties from the ASPX page so I use the following code to reference the page:

```
Router myPage = (Router)Page;
```

In Visual Studio this line comes up with the red wavy line and the error "The type or namespace name 'Router' could not be found". Strangely when I access this page on the web server one of the user controls (Home.ascx) it works fine, but another one (Product.ascx) it does not. When it doesn't work I am getting a compilation error "CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Router' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)" with the above line shown as the error line.

Even if I copy all the code from Home.ascx/.cs to Product.ascx/.cs, Product.ascx still does not work.

I am stumped!

I am guessing that the way I am referencing the ASPX page is not right and that the VS error is trying to tell me something.

Note:
1) It's a web site not a web application
2) There are no namespaces in use

Comment: With a proper architecture, your control shouldn't need to know about the page. The page should wire up to events exposed by the control for exchanging information.

Comment: ^ There always has to be one of those comments...

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that. If you consistently design strange architectures that run into these issues, perhaps you should take that as a sign and rethink how you put things together. In this case, controls are supposed to be reusable components that you can place on pages, their behavior should not be affected by the page they're on. Therefore, it's up to the control to expose its interface in a way that the page can take advantage of.

Comment: If you can't answer the question then these type of comments are generally not helpful. You don't know whether the question is asked  because someone is starting a new project or fixing/modifying someone else's code. I asked this question because I am used to working on ASP.NET "web applications" but this is a "web site" and I aren't completely familiar with some of the different requirements for an ASP.NET "web site", other than the App_Code folder. If I was hired to completely rewrite this website I would do it very differently.

Comment: A website doesn't differ from a web application very much except for the deployment process and where you need to place the code to be compiled. At runtime, they're practically the same. Whether you have inherited the project yourself or you wrote it, it's important to understand that you should fix the design so that it doesn't grate against how ASP.NET was supposed to be used. You will continue to have trouble if you have architectures where controls must access the page in order to function. It is helpful information, even if you don't want to hear it.

Comment: As far as your actual question, I suspect it's something to do with the namespaces. Is the Router class in a namespace? If not, then add one. Then add a `using <namespace>;` statement to the top of the class for your user control.

Comment: I did find the cause of my problem and a solution (see my answer). I appreciate your comments and help but fixing the design is not always an option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From some research and experimentation, it seems that because each page of an ASP.NET "Web site" project is compiled into a separate assembly, which means that code from one page is not accessible from another page or control.

However if a page uses a master page then the page can access code from the master page, although a user control added to the page cannot.

Code in the App_code folder is available to all.

The solution to my problem was to create a base class in the App_code folder that my page inherits from which includes all the methods and properties that I needed to be available to the user controls. Then in my user control I could cast the page as the base class and access these methods and properties.